# Get confused by var scope for JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am confused by the output of the following code:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 

    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log(i); 
    }, i * 1000 );

}
```

The output is 5 5 5 5 5, there is a 1-sec delay between each 5.

I know var is function scoped, but the function inside setTimeout is also in the for loop. why the output isn't 0 1 2 3 4, there is a 1-sec delay between 0 and 1, a 2-sec delay between 1 and 2, a 3-sec delay between 2 and 3, a 4-sec delay between 3 and 4?

Comment: Because `i` has changed before the time has passed

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't block, it lets the loop to continue while waiting for launching the delayed function.

Comment: @MisterJojo — No. There's only one process and one event loop.

Comment: because there is 6 differents task running at 6 differents times

Comment: @Quentin what is that process and how the event loop works behind it?